# Can't see Elasticsearch daemon

Tags: unix, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run elasticsearch as a daemon on a server.

I have run this command:

```
./bin/elasticsearch -d -p somefilename
```

but I can't find any proof of the daemon actually running, since `ps -e | grep elastic` does not produce any output. How can I see the process?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch runs on JVM. to see the PID of elasticsearch, you can use "jps" command.

with "ps ef" , only you can see java related process.

if you insist on using ps you can try this:

```
ps axms |grep -i elasticsearch
```

"axms" option show the details of all process.